# Python Hotkey to SAPI

Tags: python

I am a newbie starting to learn and develop programs in python i am currently working on a project which requires a notification to the user with a audio queue.

I am using the keyboard module (https://github.com/boppreh/keyboard) for hotkeys so when a hotkey is pressed it will run a function. My code is as follows:

```
import win32com.client
from keyboard import add_hotkey

Hotkey = 'g'

add_hotkey(Hotkey, lambda: Notification('Hello'))

def Notification(value):
   speaker = win32com.client.Dispatch("SAPI.SpVoice")
   speaker.Speak(value)
   return
```

The problem, i am facing is when this is run the script crashes and I am unable to troubleshoot the reason the error is:
[Python Console with error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nXq8j.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is something you want to do :
You need to coinitialize COM object when calling from add_key call back.

Here is official documentation :

> Before any thread can create or manipulate COM objects, it must
>   perform some preliminary initialization to establish its relationship
>   with the COM library. As a result of this process, COM creates an
>   apartment appropriate for the initialization routine: CoInitialize
>   creates a single-threaded apartment (STA), whereas CoInitializeEx with
>   the COINIT_MULTITHREADED flag produces a multi-threaded apartment. The
>   CoInitialize/CoInitializeEx call does not initialize the COM library
>   globally, only the calling thread's use of it, so it's important to
>   remember that this initialization should be done on a per-thread
>   basis.

For more [initialization Link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms809971.aspx)

**Below is the fixed code** :

```
import keyboard
import win32com.client
import pythoncom

Hotkey = 'g'


def Notification(value):
    pythoncom.CoInitialize()
    speaker = win32com.client.Dispatch("SAPI.SpVoice")
    speaker.Speak(value)


keyboard.add_hotkey(Hotkey, Notification, args=(["Hello"]))
keyboard.wait()
```

Comment: I understand what your saying, however the fixed code does not  work. It return the following "callback = lambda callback=callback: callback(*args)
TypeError: Notification() takes 1 positional argument but 5 were given"   and if i modify the Notification function with 5 arguments it runs by returns the original error https://i.stack.imgur.com/nXq8j.jpg